Customizing CPU Governor with non-performance at boot and for persistence
I looked at this, but it only outlines for specified, all-encompassing policy of "Performance".
I would like to specify a fixed frequency for my CPU, but not the max (Performance).
When I use the "CPU Frequency Scaling Monitor", and select one (19GHz) of the available frequencies (2600000 1900000 1400000 800000, or 26Ghz 19GHz 14GHz 800MHz), I see the value "userspace" reported for all instances of "/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy?/scaling_governor".
Could someone tell me
which files do I need to modify, and
what modifications do I need to make
such that
I can specify that preference in the GRUB configuration, and
I will have my selected "profile" persist beyond reboot.
Thank you in advance for your assistance.

I don't know that it can all be done via GRUB configuration, but what you want could be done via a service that executes during boot.

Thank you, @DougSmythies.  While I hesitate customizing a system I truly know nothing about, I will look into what needs to be done.  If anyone else has a suggestion about parameters that can be added to "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT", I would very much appreciate that.

For those who are interested, I also found a reference to cpupower-gui, which is independant of the Panel Applet.  I tried that, it works, but it is not what I am looking for.
